# C++ Threadpool for suspended threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

To perform some performance testing I need to start a batch of threads at a specific point within my program. Unfortunately I have to go the thread-based way and can't use tasks (std::async), because I have to pin the given threads to specific cores (using affinity). To realize this kind of behaviour I used a RAII - "one-shot" approach mentioned by [Scott Meyers](https://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=7101933101966798446&postID=2939816210857481217&bpli=1&pli=1)

This is my code so far:

```
template < class T >
typename std::decay< T >::type decay_copy( T&& v ) {
  return std::forward< T >( v );
}


/**
 * delayed thread - more or less copied from Scott Meyers:
 * http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2013/12/threadraii-thread-suspension-trouble.html
 */
class del_thread {
  private:
    using future_t          = std::shared_future< void >;
    using thread_t          = std::thread;

    enum execution_state {
      WAITING, TRIGGERED, DISMISSED 
    };

    future_t        _future;
    thread_t        _thread;

    execution_state _state  = WAITING;

  public:
    del_thread() = delete;
    del_thread( del_thread const & ) = delete;
    del_thread &operator=( del_thread const & dt ) = delete;

    del_thread( del_thread && other ):
      _future( std::move( other._future ) ),
      _thread( std::move( other._thread ) ),
      _state( std::move( other._state ) ) {
      other._state = DISMISSED;
    }

    del_thread &operator=( del_thread && dt ) {
      _future  = std::move( dt._future );
      _thread   = std::move( dt._thread );
      _state    = std::move( dt._state );
      dt._state = DISMISSED;
      return *this;
    } 

    template< typename op_t >
    del_thread( op_t && operation, future_t const & future ):
      _thread(  [ operation = decay_copy(std::forward< op_t >( operation )),
                  _future = future,
                  &_state = _state
                ]() {
                  _future.wait();
                  if( _state == TRIGGERED || _state == DISMISSED ) {
                    return;
                  }
                  _state = TRIGGERED;
                  operation();
                }
            ) {
    }

    ~del_thread() {
      join();
    }

    void join() {
      if( _state == DISMISSED ) {
        return;
      }
      if( _thread.joinable() ) {
        _thread.join();
      }
    }
};

class batch_thread_pool {
  private:
    std::promise< void > _promise;
    std::shared_future< void > _future;
    std::vector< del_thread > _pool;

  public:
    batch_thread_pool() :
      _future( _promise.get_future().share() ) {}
    template< typename op_t >
    void add_thread( op_t && operation ) {
      _pool.emplace_back( del_thread(std::forward< op_t >( operation ), std::ref( _future ) ) );
    }

    void run_batch() {
      _promise.set_value();
      _pool.clear();
    }
};
```

The basic idea is to use a void-future to create a suspended thread, perform the thread setup stuff like setting affinity and / or priority and start all threads at the same time. As one can see, the main thread should join the added threads when the pool is cleared. To test the threadpool I wrote a little main, looking like that:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include "threads.h"

void runFunc() {
  std::cout << "In runFunc...\n";
  return;
}
void run2Func() {
  std::cout << "In run2Func...\n";
  return;
}

int main() {
  batch_thread_pool tp;
  tp.add_thread( runFunc );
  tp.add_thread( run2Func );
  std::cout << "Working while thread 'suspended'...\n";
  tp.run_batch();
  std::cout << "Working while thread runs asynchronously...\n";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 500 ) );
  std::cout << "Done!\n";
}
```

Unfortunately the Threads are not started consistently. Sometimes both methods (runFunc and run2Func) are executed, sometimes only one of them. I guess it is, because the main thread ends, before a join happens. Is this correct or does anyone knows, what I am doing wrong?

Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
execution_state _state;
```

if you want to support these objects moving, this cannot be in automatic storage.

Honestly, the only use I can think for it would be `ABORT`.  Moved-from `thread`s are not joinable...

```
class del_thread {
private:
  using future_t      = std::shared_future< void >;
  using thread_t      = std::thread;

  enum execution_state {
    WAITING, TRIGGERED, ABORT
  };

  std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<execution_state>> _state =
    std::make_unique<std::atomic<execution_state>>(WAITING);

  future_t    _future;
  thread_t    _thread;

public:
  void abort() const {
    if (_state) *_state = ABORT;
  }
  del_thread() = delete;
  del_thread( del_thread const & ) = delete;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread const & dt ) = delete;

  del_thread( del_thread && other ) = default;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread && dt ) = default;

  template< class op_t >
  del_thread( op_t && operation, future_t const & future ):
    _thread(
      [
        operation = std::forward< op_t >( operation ),
        _future = future,
        _state = _state.get()
      ]()
      {
        _future.wait();
        if (*_state == ABORT) return;
        *_state = TRIGGERED;
        operation();
      }
    )
  {}

  ~del_thread() {
    join();
  }

  void join() {
    if( !_state ) {
      return;
    }
    if( _thread.joinable() ) {
      _thread.join();
    }
  }
};
```

if you don't want abort:

```
class del_thread {
private:
  using future_t      = std::shared_future< void >;
  using thread_t      = std::thread;

  future_t    _future;
  thread_t    _thread;

public:
  del_thread() = delete;
  del_thread( del_thread const & ) = delete;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread const & dt ) = delete;

  del_thread( del_thread && other ) = default;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread && dt ) = default;

class del_thread {
private:
  using future_t      = std::shared_future< void >;
  using thread_t      = std::thread;

  future_t    _future;
  thread_t    _thread;

public:
  del_thread() = delete;
  del_thread( del_thread const & ) = delete;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread const & dt ) = delete;

  del_thread( del_thread && other ) = default;
  del_thread &operator=( del_thread && dt ) = default;

  template< class op_t >
  del_thread( op_t && operation, future_t const & future ):
    _thread(
      [
        operation = std::forward< op_t >( operation ),
        _future = future
      ]()
      {
        _future.wait();
        operation();
      }
    )
  {}

  ~del_thread() {
    join();
  }

  void join() {
    if( _thread.joinable() ) {
      _thread.join();
    }
  }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecea6a5261497094).

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks alot! Unfortunately I am struggeling with forwarding a parameter pack into the lambda! I will accept the answer as soon as I can validate it properly! :)